# Dans ou sur une échelle (mesure)

Tags: usage, prépositions

Deux tournures :

> La température se mesure en kelvins (K) **sur / dans une échelle** créée pour les besoins de la thermodynamique.

Je les ai vues toutes les deux. Laquelle est la plus correcte ?

Comment: Dans ce cas il en reste une seule ; on ne dit pas « J'ai vu toutes les deux tournures. » Je ne saurais pas dire pourquoi ; ce qui peut être dit, si on vient d'utiliser le mot « tournure » c'est « Je les ai vues toutes les deux. » ; sinon il faut dire « Jai vu les deux tournures. ».

Comment: J'oubliais, on peut aussi dire ceci, sans que les expressions aient été mentionnées par le mot « tournure » : « J'ai vu ces tournures toutes les deux. ». Ça serait votre meilleur choix.

Comment: Oui, ça va parce que la phrase précédente commence par « Deux tournures » ; en dépit de cela on peut si on le veut, répéter « tournure », c'est à dire utiliser l'autre forme avec « tournure » dedans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personnellement j'ai presque toujours vu *sur l'échelle* quand on parle d'échelle de mesure dans un contexte scientifique. Par exemple quand on parle de séisme, on parle de *magnitude **sur** l'échelle de Richter*, jamais de *magnitude **dans** l'échelle de Richter* (en tout cas je n'ai jamais lu/entendu la deuxième forme).

Comment: Tu as été plus rapide que moi pour la réponse, mais je confirme. On dit bien "sur une échelle" et pas "dans" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Il faut utiliser « sur. »

On mesure sur une échelle comme on monte sur une échelle.

« Dans » signifie que l'objet se trouve *à l'intérieur*.